# What is this marking on a German truck?

Tags: sniper-elite-4

I have spotted this marking on a few trucks in Sniper Elite 4 and I would like to know what it means...

[image]

Does it mark this vehicle as belonging to a certain category perhaps (two axles with a non-rigid rear covering, but a solid cab)?

I don't think I've noticed anything else similar on other materiel depicted in the game.

Speculation/conspiracy theories welcome :)

Comment: it means the driver likes to go roller skating

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During WWII, the Germans devised a system of tactical symbols.

This picture details what these symbols mean:

[image: Symbols]

I believe it's number 16 in the picture, which meant armored car.

<sub>[(Source)](http://militaria.forum-xl.com/viewtopic.php?f=78&t=665)</sub>

**Additional Information**: I've found a [large PDF](http://cgsc.cdmhost.com/cdm/ref/collection/p4013coll8/id/2805) that you can download and look at.  It is a manual that was constructed by the United States as well as Britain that depicts and defines what all these symbols mean.  On page 26 of the PDF, you can see the close symbol again.  The German word for this vehicle is *Panzerspähwagen* which according to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#de/en/Panzersp%C3%A4hwagen), is Armored Car.  The United States referred to these cars as *Scout Cars*, while Britain referred to them as *Armd C*.

Comment: Very interesting, I will have a look out for more of these in the game and add a montage of them to my Q.  Accepted & +1

Comment: BTW, I find it highly ironic that they marked this vehicle as "armoured car" when it can be completely obliterated by a single carefully aimed suppressed pistol shot from 60 metres away. :)

Comment: @Wossname I added some additional information and found a PDF that contains definitions for the tactical symbols used by the Germans. It's actually pretty interesting!

Comment: Try this... Compare #28 with a google image search for "German post office".  Looks like they didn't even try to obfuscate that at all.  Fascinating.

Comment: @Wossname Looks like the [Deutsche Post logo evolved](http://logos.wikia.com/wiki/Deutsche_Post) from the trumpet looking instrument to what is it today. Page 171 in the PDF has the symbol for the Post office as well if you want to see it - looks like there were a few.

Comment: @TimmyJim No, the horn as symbol for the German postal service predates even World War One. Here it is on [the flag used from 1892 to 1918](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posthorn#/media/File:Postflagge_1892-1918.svg).